# Nginx extensionless PHP rewrite not working

Tags: php, nginx, url-rewriting

I have been trying to rewrite my `php` pages so that they display without their extensions in the browser. For example, a link on my server at `www.example.com` loads a page called `about-us.php` and in the browser, the user would see `www.example.com/about-us`.

I have been trying to follow these tutorials to try and get this to work, but sadly they are not working.

[Tweak Talk Link](http://www.tweaktalk.net/60/nginx-remove-php-file-extension-from-url)

[Stack Overflow Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21911297/how-to-remove-both-php-and-html-extensions-from-url-using-nginx)

Here is my nginx `sites-available/default` file content.

```
# Server Block
server {
    # Listening Ports
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    # Root Location Initialization
    root /home/zach/Documents/Workspaces/www;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    # Server Name
    server_name localhost;

    # Root Location
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ @extensionless-php;
    }

    # Error pages
    error_page 404 /404.html;
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root /home/zach/Documents/Workspaces/www;
    }

    # PHP Handling
    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    # Extensionless PHP
    location @extensionless-php {
        rewrite ^(.*)$ $1.php last;
    }
}
```

All of my links to `php` pages still display the `.php` extension in the browser, does anyone have any solutions to my problem?

Comment: This question might be better suited for [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/)

Comment: @AlphaDelta this question is about nginx - it *directly involves tools used primarily for programming*

Comment: Definitely Server Fault.

Comment: @scrowler exactly this is a question about nginx, a *server software*, it is not a programming or scripting problem.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following line to the exact spot where you think it'd form a loop! :-)

```
if ($request_uri ~ ^/([^?]*)\.php($|\?)) {  return 302 /$1?$args;  }
```

More info here: [nginx remove .php and .html file extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24225145/nginx-remove-php-and-html-file-extension/32966347#32966347)