# NGINX remove .html extension

Tags: html, nginx

So, I found an answer to removing the .html extension on my page, that works fine with this code:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name _;
    root /var/www/html/;
    index index.html;

    if (!-f "${request_filename}index.html") {
        rewrite ^/(.*)/$ /$1 permanent;
    }

    if ($request_uri ~* "/index.html") {
        rewrite (?i)^(.*)index\.html$ $1 permanent;
    }   

    if ($request_uri ~* ".html") {
        rewrite (?i)^(.*)/(.*)\.html $1/$2 permanent;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri.html $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
}
```

But if I open mypage.com it redirects me to mypage.com/index

Wouldn't this be fixed by declaring index.html as index? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 158, accepted):

## The "Holy Grail" Solution for Removing ".html" in NGINX:

**UPDATED ANSWER:** This question piqued my curiosity, and I went on another, more in-depth search for a "holy grail" solution for `.html` redirects in NGINX. Here is the link to the answer I found, since I didn't come up with it myself: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32966347/4175718

However, I'll give an example and explain how it works. Here is the code:

```
location / {
    if ($request_uri ~ ^/(.*)\.html(\?|$)) {
        return 302 /$1;
    }
    try_files $uri $uri.html $uri/ =404;
}
```

What's happening here is a pretty ingenious use of the `if` directive. NGINX runs a regex on the `$request_uri` portion of incoming requests. The regex checks if the URI has an .html extension and then stores the extension-less portion of the URI in the built-in variable `$1`.

From the [docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html), since it took me a while to figure out where the `$1` came from:

> Regular expressions can contain captures that are made available for later reuse in the $1..$9 variables.

The regex both checks for the existence of unwanted .html requests and effectively sanitizes the URI so that it does not include the extension. Then, using a simple `return` statement, the request is redirected to the sanitized URI that is now stored in `$1`.

The best part about this, as original author [cnst](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1122270/cnst) explains, is that

> Due to the fact that $request_uri is always constant per request, and is not affected by other rewrites, it won't, in fact, form any infinite loops.

Unlike the rewrites, which operate on **any** `.html` request (including the invisible internal redirect to `/index.html`), this solution only operates on external URIs that are visible to the user.

### What does "try_files" do?

You will still need the `try_files` directive, as otherwise NGINX will have no idea what to do with the newly sanitized extension-less URIs. The `try_files` directive shown above will first try the new URL by itself, then try it with the ".html" extension, then try it as a directory name.

The NGINX docs also explain how the default `try_files` directive works. The default `try_files` directive is ordered differently than the example above so the explanation below does not perfectly line up:

> NGINX will first append `.html` to the end of the URI and try to serve it. If it finds an appropriate `.html` file, it will return that file and will **maintain the extension-less URI**. If it cannot find an appropriate `.html` file, it will try the URI without any extension, then the URI as a directory, and then finally return a 404 error.

### UPDATE: What does the regex do?

The above answer touches on the use of regular expressions, but here is a more specific explanation for those who are still curious. The following regular expression (regex) is used:

```
^/(.*)\.html(\?|$)
```

This breaks down as:

`^`: indicates beginning of line.

`/`: match the character "/" literally. Forward slashes do NOT need to be escaped in NGINX.

`(.*)`: capturing group: match any character an unlimited number of times

`\.`: match the character "." literally. This must be escaped with a backslash.

`html`: match the string "html" literally.

`(\?|$)`: match a literal "?" or the end of the string. This is done to avoid mishandling file names with something after ".html".

The capturing group `(.*)` is what contains the non-".html" portion of the URL. This can later be referenced with the variable `$1`. NGINX is then configured to re-try the request (`return 302 /$1;`) and the `try_files` directive internally re-appends the ".html" extension so the file can be located.

### UPDATE: Retaining the query string

To retain query strings and arguments passed to a `.html` page, the `return` statement can be changed to:

```
return 302 /$1$is_args$args;
```

This should allow requests such as `/index.html?test` to redirect to `/index?test` instead of just `/index`.

---

#### Note that this is considered safe usage of the `if` directive.

From the NGINX page If Is Evil:

> The only 100% safe things which may be done inside if in a location context are:
>
> return ...;
>
> rewrite ... last;

---

#### Also, note that you may swap out the '302' redirect for a '301'.

A `301` redirect is permanent, and is cached by web browsers and search engines. If your goal is to permanently remove the `.html` extension from pages that are already indexed by a search engine, you will want to use a `301` redirect. However, if you are testing on a live site, it is best practice to start with a `302` and only move to a `301` when you are absolutely confident your configuration is working correctly.

Comment: How come you use a 302 redirect instead of 301?

Comment: @WillB Since 301 redirects are cached by browsers, I like to use 302's unless I am 100% sure I'll never want to undo the redirect. From what I've seen, Google doesn't seem to care too much, and it makes it a lot easier if one day you decide you want to go back to .html extensions in your URLs.

Comment: @goliatone I think you're right. That's how I have it in my production code, so I've fixed it in this answer.

Comment: What does the regex ~ ^/(.*)\. do? And how does the URL part without the extension get cut out? How does $1 know that

Comment: @CristianMatthiasAmbæk edited answer to explain how the regex works.

Comment: What's the purpose of the if statement? How is it more efficient than if you were to simply define a separate location block to handle requests matching the regex?

Comment: @miknik I haven't tried it that way, so I can't say for certain if that works.

Comment: If you're planning on redirecting any given page for longer than a day or so I think the recommended way is to 301, not 302.

Comment: @DonovanDikaio See comments above. 302 is used here because this is a redirect you may want to undo at some point.

Comment: @arnon at no time in the posters question does he imply that his removal of the extension need to be a temporary redirect.

Comment: @DonovanDikaio You're absolutely correct, and I realize the OP used `permanent` in their `rewrite` rule. However, I think I'd rather leave the example as 302 instead of 301. My hope is that experienced users will know how to implement a 301 and that inexperienced users looking for code to copy/paste will not accidentally get burned by a permanent redirect. I may further edit the answer to clarify this.

Comment: great answer, and love the detailed explanation for everything that is involved in the solution, but the part on retaining the query string is wrong.  As $request_uri is the full url of the original request, it won't match a regex ending \.html$ - because $ denotes the absolute end of the string, and of course the query string follows .html!  So the answer should be corrected to include (for retaining the query string) that the location regex is "if ($request_url ~ ^/(.*)\.html)" and the return statement is best stated as "return 302 /$1/$is_args$args;" to c/f any optional query string

Comment: If some of you copy and past the script above don't forget to delete below orginal script in config file out.

 location / {
    root   html;
    index  index.html index.htm;            
     }

Comment: @AndyLorenz Thanks! You're exactly right. I've updated the answer.

Comment: this is an excellent example of how an answer on stack overflow should be

Comment: This is a really complete tutorial for setting the clean URI without extension. Thank you so much for explaning so much details so that I can learn as well.

Comment: In some tests I did the code above caused the HTTPS to be lost. Example: https:/mysite.com/contact.html -> http:/mysite.com/contact I solved this by making a small adjustment to the return. `return 301 https://$host/$1$is_args$args;`

Comment: Note that this answer breaks on certain inputs, e.g. "some-page.html-entities-tests.html" (real-world example). A more robust rewrite is:

`if ($request_uri ~ ^/(.*)\\.html(\?|$)) { return 302 /$1$is_args$args; }`

Comment: Combined with `index index.html;` and a small adjustment: `if ($request_uri ~ ^/(.*)(\.html|index)(\?|$))` this is perfect! Redirects `/index.html` -> `/index` -> `/` and finds the index page at root.

Answer (score 2):

This has often come up for me as well and due to the configuration at work, location blocks are iffy at best and the / & .php blocks are locked down. Which means that most of the solutions don't work for me.

So here is one that I simplified from the Accepted answer above.

```
rewrite ^/(.*)\.html /$1/ permanent;
```

Works great for CMSs, where the underlying framework is generating the pages

Comment: I believe the issue I ran into with the rewrite method was that /index.html would get redirected to /index. This either caused an infinite loop or it caused the landing page to become www.example.com/index.