# Nginx : How to remove .html from URL and get paramiter

Tags: javascript, nginx, web-applications

I tried to get a param form (domainname/page.html?param=1), it works.

But the URL is preferred (domain name/page?param=1), it doesn't work.

Do you have any idea to remove .html form URL?

Comment: You should look in to URL Routing.

Comment: Maybe it helps http://cobwwweb.com/remove-html-extension-and-trailing-slash-in-nginx-config

Comment: or this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/38238001/9210255

Comment: thank for helping @TigerTV.ru but not work, i try before post this. T^T

Comment: Similar your question https://serverfault.com/questions/439284/nginx-rewrite-remove-html-from-url-with-arguments

Comment: oh, i think so and i'm sorry I did not find it.