# Shiny server redirection stopped working when added option to remove .html extension

Tags: nginx, digital-ocean, shiny-server

I'm trying to add options to nginx.conf file, to allow my pages work without .html extension. [I used that solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38228393/nginx-remove-html-extension)

However as soon as I added that piece of code

```
server {

    listen   80;
    server_name mydomain.co *.mydomain.co;

    location / {
        if ($request_uri ~ ^/(.*)\.html$) {
            return 302 /$1;
        }
        try_files $uri $uri.html $uri/ =404;

    }
  }
```

my shiny server and rstudio redirection stopped working. Redirection is set inside sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default
and looks like this

```
location /shiny/ {
 proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3838/;
proxy_http_version 1.1;
proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
rewrite ^(/shiny/[^/]+)$ $1/ permanent;

}



location /rstudio/ {
  proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8787/;
proxy_http_version 1.1;
proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
}
```

. I tried to put if function there but didn't work.

Comment: Which file are you editing? Are all the locations in your question supposed to be in the same `server` block?

Comment: They are in 2 different locations first one is in /usr/share/nginx/www second one is in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default. I tried to put redirection from one file to the other, but then nginx didnt want to restart