# How to remove .html file extension from URL

Tags: .htaccess

I am trying to remove the `.html` file extension from the URLs of my site.

All the answers I've found are about .htaccess and the little snippet of code which is required, but that doesn't work at all, even after removing the .html extensions from the file names. The code pasted below is what I've tried.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]`
```

I simply wanted to make my site look more professional, because after all, it's not 2005 anymore.

Edit: I'm just about a complete beginner to HTML and CSS as a whole, so please walk me through possible fixes. Thanks!

Comment: You need to have server or use some spa router

Comment: it depends how you built your website, which technologies u used

Comment: Are you sure you're running on Apache httpd web server? That's what this configuration applies to. If you have different server software, you'll need different configuration.

Comment: Hello there, `.htaccess` is for apache and we expect here that you are using it. The question does not hold the tag about apache but the [HTML] tag which is not related to this question as it is not about HTML but rather about apache and .htaccess. Let's stay on-topic.

Comment: Looks like nginx is serving up your site, so Possible duplicate of [NGINX remove .html extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38228393/nginx-remove-html-extension)

Comment: @AuxTaco What is the name of the file where I should put the code?

Comment: [Depends on how nginx was installed.](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/basic-functionality/managing-configuration-files/) Try `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` first.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have your pages under http://www.yoursite.com/html, the following .htaccess rules apply.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /html/(.*).html\ HTTP/
   RewriteRule .* http://localhost/html/%1 [R=301,L]

   RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /html/(.*)\ HTTP/
   RewriteRule .* %1.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Here's what it does when I remove .html from the URL: https://imgur.com/5n4SYUm 

Am I doing something wrong?