# Cannot remove .html from url

Tags: docker, nginx, mod-rewrite, docker-compose, nginx-config

I have a static site and I'm trying to remove the `.html` from the url, so when I visit the site `www.example.com/home.html` I should get: `www.example.com/home`.

This is my project structure:

```
project
    docker
       nginx
           conf.d
               default.conf
    www
        index.html
        home.html
        services.html
docker-compose.yml
```

This is the `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: '3.6'

services:
  my-app:
    container_name: trasauto_nginx
    image: nginx:stable-alpine
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - "./www/:/usr/share/nginx/html"
      - ./docker/nginx/conf.d/:/etc/nginx/conf.d
    expose:
      - 80

networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: proxy
```

and this is the `default.conf`:

```
server {
    try_files $uri.html $uri $uri/ =404;
}
```

I tried to remove the `.html` part from the url, but for some reason I get:

> 404 not found

what I did wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add some more lines to your Nginx configuration in order to have what you want. I think this question has already been answered in detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38238001/16198415).

**Edited.**
Here's an example Nginx configuration that should work

```
server {
    listen 80;    
    index index.html;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html;

    location / {
        if ($request_uri ~ ^/(.*)\.html) {
            return 302 /$1;
        }
        try_files $uri $uri.html $uri/ =404;
    }
}
```

You need to specify the root directory from which you're serving your static files.

Comment: I already tried that .. I added the `location` directive within `server` but I still get 404

Comment: Well, you probably need a bit more lines in your configuration. I didn't realize you only had this one. I'll edit the answer and include the example configuration.

Comment: You're right! That's why didn't worked before, now is working fine, many thanks and have a good day!