# Nginx try_files directive doesn't serve the specified files

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

I know there is lots of similar posts out there but still couldn't find the one fits my case.

I have very simple location block which serves static html file but it serve 404 not the file i specified.

```
location / {
    if ($request_uri != /abcd) {
        return 500;
    }

    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    #try_files $uri.html =404;
    #try_files index2.html =404;
    try_files $uri $uri/  =404;
}
```

And this is output of ls in root directory

```bash
50x.html  abcd.html  index.html  index2.html
```

As you can see there is abcd.html and index2.html but when i set the file name it can't be reached and shows 404 page.

Only `$uri.html` can be resolved and shows the right page. What should i do if i want to serve the static file for the location?

For example i want to server `abcd.html` for the request `/abcd` and return 500 for the other requests.

Comment: Did `try_files $uri.html =404;` not work?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NGINX remove .html extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38228393/nginx-remove-html-extension)

Comment: @Phil Only `try_files $uri.html` works but what i want is that i want serve specific static file for example `hello.html` whether `$uri` is match

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All Nginx URIs contain a leading `/`.

The *file* parameter of the `try_files` directive requires a leading `/` to match the specified path. See `try_files` [manual page](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files).

The `$uri` variable already contains a leading `/`.

So:

- `try_files $uri.html =404;` matches a file because `$uri.html` == `/abcd.html`
- `try_files index2.html =404;` does not match a file as it's missing a leading `/`
- `try_files $uri $uri/  =404;` does not match a file as there is no file called `abcd`

For example:

```
root /usr/share/nginx/html;

location / {
    return 500;
}
location = /abcd {
    try_files /index2.html =404;
}
```

Assuming that `index2.html` always exists, the `=404` is never reached.

Comment: Excellent explanation! This is exactly what i want to know. Thank you so much