# How do I redirect "website/page" to "website/page.html" when people type it in browser (pretty-url)

Tags: html, web, pretty-urls

I recently started using a static site with godaddy.com without a cms. It's a basic website I uploaded and is only html/js/css.

When people type "website.com/page" they get 404 not found.
When they type "website.com/page.html" they get the correct page.

How can I fix my site so users can simply type "website/page" and not be forced to type "website/page.html" without using php?

## SOLUTION

After researching the information about .htaccess files provided by @Gijsberts (thank you), I did the following:

1. Created a .htaccess file on server.
2. Added the following code:

   # Remove the .html extension from html files
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]

Comment: is it simple static html site without any CMS?

Comment: @RomanNazarkin correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most CMS systems have a .htaccess file what handles the redirect and the 404 errors. In CMS system they are most called "Pretty-urls". Read the links below to set up those pretty urls yourself with a static web page without a cms.

- https://mediatemple.net/community/products/grid/204643080/how-do-i-redirect-my-site-using-a-htaccess-file
- http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/using-htaccess-files-for-pretty-urls--net-6049

Answer (score -1):

You normally can do this with your **Webserver** config. In **Apache** you have this enabled automatically. In **nginx** you should have a look at this [tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21911297/how-to-remove-both-php-and-html-extensions-from-url-using-nginx).

If you are using [caddy](https://caddyserver.com) you have to config your caddyfile like

```
ext .html .htm .php
```

if you are using microsoft iis have a look at [microsofts tutorial](https://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/requestfiltering/fileextensions).

Let me know if you are using something else or need more help.

**EDIT**

If you are using a **webspace** you may are not able to change the config of the webserver. you now can use **.htaccess**. create a .htaccess file and write down something like

```
Options +MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```