# nginx - Rewrite url for php files

Tags: nginx

I recently moved a website which used Apache to Nginx.

How can I get an url which looks like this:

```
http://example.com/login
```

to point to `http://example.com/login.php` while keeping the .php out of the url?

My current configuration:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    root /var/www/example.com/html/;
    index index.php index.html;

    server_name example.com www.example.com;

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    # deny accessing php files for the /assets directory
    location ~ ^/assets/.*\.php$ {
            deny all;
    }

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
     location ~ \.php$ {
             include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;

             # With php7.0-cgi alone:
             # fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
             # With php7.0-fpm:
             fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually use something like this and it's SEO proof. Tested by a lot of my client sites, works like a charm.

In your /etc/nginx/conf.d/domain.tld.conf file include this :

```
server {
  index index.html index.php;
  location / {
    if ($request_uri ~ ^/(.*)\.html$) {  return 302 /$1;  }
    try_files $uri $uri/ $uri.html $uri.php?$args;
  }
  location ~ \.php$ {
    if ($request_uri ~ ^/([^?]*)\.php($|\?)) {  return 302 /$1?$args;  }
    try_files $uri =404;
    # add fastcgi_pass line here, depending if you use socket or port
  }
}
```

[Source i used a while a go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21911297/how-to-remove-both-php-and-html-extensions-from-url-using-nginx)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In my current configuration ... how would it work? I tried but the nginx server didn't restart.