# Remove .php from Url using Plesk Directives

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting, plesk

i'm using plesk onyx and nginx
Is there anyway to remove the .php from my links using directives ?
here is what i have so far but i still have .php at the end of url

```
    #ignored: condition 0
if ($http_host ~* "^www\."){
    set $rule_0 1;
    break;
}
if ($rule_0 = "1"){
    rewrite ^/ https://example.com$uri permanent;
}
rewrite ^/directory/([A-Za-z-]+)/?$ https://example.com/directory/$1.php last;
rewrite ^/rss/medicinecategory.php$ https://example.com/directory/medical-specialties permanent;
rewrite ^/rss/medicalconditions.php$ https://example.com/directory/medical-conditions permanent;
rewrite ^/rss/cancers.php$ https://example.com/directory/cancers permanent;
rewrite ^/rss/infectiousdiseases.php$ https://example.com/directory/infectious-diseases permanent;
rewrite ^/rss/surgical_procedures.php$ https://example.com/directory/medical-procedures permanent;
rewrite ^/rss/therapies.php$ https://example.com/directory/therapies permanent;
rewrite ^/rss/vaccines.php$ https://example.com/directory/vaccines permanent;
rewrite ^/rss/drugs.php$ https://example.com/directory/drugs permanent;
rewrite ^/rss/health_management.php$ https://example.com/directory/health-management permanent;
rewrite ^/rss/medical_education.php$ https://example.com/directory/medical-training permanent;
if ($args ~ "podcasts|blogs|news"){
    set $rule_12 1$rule_12;
}
if ($rule_12 = "1"){
    rewrite ^/rss/index.php/Consumer-Health-Advice/91/$ https://example.com/rss/index.php/Consumer-Health-News/26/ permanent;
}
rewrite ^/rss/index.php/Consumer-Health-Advice/91/$ https://example.com/rss/index.php/Consumer-Health-News/26/$1? permanent;
```

Answer (score 1):

A similar issue was discussed on [How to remove both .php and .html extensions from url using NGINX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21911297/how-to-remove-both-php-and-html-extensions-from-url-using-nginx).

This answer looks useful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21915845/4508593