# Nginx .htaccess doesn't work in linux server

Tags: linux, .htaccess, nginx

hi everyone i have just created website to myself and i editted links using .htaccess (111.111.111.111/list.php | like 111.111.111.111/list ) not include php extension. but when i put files into my linux server, it doesn't work my linux nginx server. when i write 111.111.111.111/list on the url box, it display 404 not found page. it wants to me write 111.111.111.111/list.php
and everything is working on my computer localhost. 
(i didnt buy domain name i just use only server's ip)
 please help me
by the way i apologize for my english.

Comment: Without any config details, no one can help.

Comment: like what config details ? .htaccess ? i mean is there any options for nginx

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Web Applications Stack Exchange](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/), [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nginx does not support .htaccess-files because of performance reasons. 
https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/likeapache-htaccess/

You have to do this inside of the nginx configuration file.
To remove the .php maybe this helps:

[How to remove both .php and .html extensions from url using NGINX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21911297/how-to-remove-both-php-and-html-extensions-from-url-using-nginx)

If you really need .htaccess, you have to use apache instead of nginx.