# NGINX rewrite issue for index.php

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I have an issue as given below.

Say I have a site example.com and I have made modifications to the rewrite logic to remove .php extensions. The code given below works fine in all the cases except for index.php

https://example.com --> Not accessible. This is not correct. It should display contents from index.php page.
https://example.com/index.php --> Displays 404 page. This is correct.
https://example.com/index --> Displays index page. This is not correct.

```
server {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    error_page 404 /error/custom_404;

    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        index index.php index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri $uri/  @missing;
    }
    location ~*  \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js|svg)$ {
        expires 365d;
    } 

    location ~* (\.php$|myadmin) {
    return 404;
    }
    location @missing {
            if (!-f $document_root$uri.php) { return 404; }
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME "$document_root$uri.php";
            fastcgi_param PATH_TRANSLATED "$document_root$uri.php";
            fastcgi_param QUERY_STRING    $args;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;
            }

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    location ~* \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    }

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }

    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot


}server {
    if ($host = www.example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot




}
```

Can someone point to where I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove both .php and .html extensions from url using NGINX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21911297/how-to-remove-both-php-and-html-extensions-from-url-using-nginx)

Comment: See the accepted answer of the duplicate I indicated. You can add an [`internal` directive](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#internal) to the `location ~ \.php$` block to prevent direct access to URIs ending with `.php`.

Comment: @RichardSmith: It is not duplicate in the sense that the link you indicated contains the solution that was implemented, but in my case I do not want to navigate to the index page like http://example.com/index  

What I want is I should be able to navigate to http://example.com and the server needs to serve me the page from http://example.com/index.php without appending index.php or index

Currently if I naviage to http://example.com it throws me 404 error