# Nginx config: route all .php files via index except if it contains a path to the file manager

Tags: php, nginx, server, nginx-config

I'm working on the new project, which will have many redirects from the old website uris. Many of the old uris contain the `.php` extension in the `uri` and Nginx tries to load them as a file rather than fall back to our redirect controller method.

To make it a bit more tricky, we are using wysiwyg editor with the file manager, which, when called - uses `.php` extension so this one needs to be excluded.

Effectively I would like it to work the way so that when I call for instance old `uri` such as `/old-page/path/file.php` it will route it via `index.php` but when I call `/vendor/ckfinder/plugins/filemanager/dialog.php?...` it will load the actual file.

I've seen this post, which doesn't really resolve what I'm after, but I think it's a good starting point [How to remove both .php and .html extensions from url using NGINX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21911297/how-to-remove-both-php-and-html-extensions-from-url-using-nginx)

My existing setup is

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

**UPDATE**

I tried @Richard Smith suggestion, which after reading the docs I think should work, but unfortunately, for whatever reason - it doesn't - here's what I tried:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri /index.php?$query_string;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
    include fastcgi_params;
}
```

So `try_files` checks if `$uri` exists - and if it doesn't it falls back to `/index.php?$query_string;`, which should point the request to `index.php`. Any idea what I might be missing here?

Answer (score 2):

If the PHP files do not exist on the new server, the simplest solution is to redirect any non-existent PHP files to `/index.php` - just as you do for non-PHP URIs.

For example:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}
location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri /index.php?$query_string;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
    include fastcgi_params;
}
```

The `fastcgi_split_path_info` and `fastcgi_index` statements and not required in this particular `location` block.

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) for more.

Comment: I have added a link to the `try_files` manual page. The short answer is no - it will **only** redirect those `.php` files that **do not exist** on this server.

Comment: Thanks - I'll give it a try.

Comment: I'm afraid it doesn't work - doesn't really do anything - things are working the same way as before. I've restarted Nginx after applying changes etc.