# NGINX 404 all pages

Tags: nginx

So I have two issues that I am trying to do. First I am trying to understand NGINX and use it for redirects and everything as well; however, if I try to remove the extensions from the php / html files it just downloads the file. If I use another thing to just try (without the file extension try) it just gives me 404s. I am not sure what the issue is nor what I am doing wrong.

First I'll show my remove php file extension issue:

```
server {
    listen 443;
    server_name XXX.XX.XX.XX;

    root /var/www/html;
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri.html $uri/ @extensionless-php;
        index index.html index.htm index.php;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
    }

    location @extensionless-php {
        rewrite ^(.*)$ $1.php last;
    }
}
```

Here is my other code to fix the problem above (but just gives me 404s)

```
server {
    listen 443;
    server_name XXX.XX.XX.XX;

    root /var/www/html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    error_page 404 /404.html;
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root /var/www/html;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

XXX.XX.XX.XX is my the servers ip.

PS: I have read that I need the bottom section first to get the top section working.

Sources include:

[How to remove both .php and .html extensions from url using NGINX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21911297/how-to-remove-both-php-and-html-extensions-from-url-using-nginx)

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-nginx-mysql-php-lemp-stack-on-ubuntu-14-04

Ty for your help.

UPDATES: 
Kuldeep KD - 770 /var/www/html (not solution but thanks)
Jignesh Joisar - Trying port 80 (failed but per usual thanks)

Comment: may be change a port `443` to `80`

Comment: I force everything to port https (aka port 443)

Comment: change this line `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;`

Comment: Tried this as well and still 404s. Maybe I am an idiot but does this go into the default-ssl.conf? Maybe I am putting it in the wrong file.

Comment: i think first of try load site in port 80 then u load site in 443 beacause you can not direct load 443 port site u must redirect to 80 to 443

Comment: Yeah i redirect: return 301 https://$host$request_uri;

Comment: Tried putting this on port 80 as well and it fails. =[

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181350/discussion-between-deadweight-and-jignesh-joisar).

Answer (score 0):

Check for necessary permissions on /var/www/html
you can change the permissions using

```
chmod -R 770 /var/www/html/
```

also check for the owner of directory you may have to change that as well, depends on user your nginx is using.

```
chown -R user:group /var/www/html
```

Comment: Hey, I tried this and sadly nothing, Still 404s and downloads the file. Also, I don't have a group user so the second part wont work. TY tho

Answer (score 0):

try to this one in `80` port

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;


    root /var/www/html/;


    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name localhost;

    error_page 404 /404.html;
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;   
    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
         try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    # pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server
    #
    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri /index.php =404;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

Comment: i think u share your all conf file in question

Comment: What do you mean my "all conf file"?

Comment: Gimme a moment, I have a better idea to help.

Comment: @Deadweight create a chat