# How to rewrite .php extension to no ending on Nginx?

Tags: php, nginx, url-rewriting

I'm trying to become my php files running without `.php` extension ending in browser and redirect all to non `.php`

I've already setup, that both available. With .php and without `.php` on browser. But now just need a rewrite.

Did u can help me out their?

```
location / {
        try_files $uri $uri $uri/ @extensionless-php;
    }

    location @extensionless-php {
        rewrite ^(.*)$ $1.php last;
    }
```

Best regards

Comment: Have you try this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/21911610/8828489?

Comment: Ist just the same without this: `location / {
    index index.html index.htm index.php;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
}` - where `index index.html index.htm index.php;` already defined in root directory and dont think try_files is for an rewrite ^^ On my side just the rewrite from .php to without is missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You presumably have a `location ~ \.php` block to process URIs which end with `.php`. And you should include a `try_files $uri =404;` statement in that block to avoid [passing uncontrolled requests to PHP](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/#passing-uncontrolled-requests-to-php).

You can also add an `internal` directive to that block, which will prevent external access to the `.php` URI, so that only your extensionless PHP URIs will work. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#internal) for details.

For example:

```
location ~ \.php$ (
    internal;
    try_files $uri =404;
    ...
}
```

If you want to redirect the browser to use extensionless PHP when a URI ending with `.php` is inadvertently presented, you need to look at the original request URI, otherwise you risk a redirection loop.

For example:

```
if ($request_uri ~ \.php($|\?))
{
    rewrite ^(.*)\.php$ $1 permanent;
}
```

See [this caution](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/) on the use of `if`.