# NGINX conditional Rewrite extensionless URLS

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I am trying to provide extensionless URLs for a client. The systems URLs will be generated without the extension in the navigation elements and links so I will have links that look like.

```
www.somesite.com
www.somesite.com/foo
www.somesite.com/foo/bar
www.somesite.com/bar/foo/barfoo
```

lets pretend for a moment that the calls will be either routed to a proxy that can handle a defined file extension or simply serve the html page if it exists. If the url is correctly rewritten then I would think a location command with a matching regex for the extension should work.

so behind the scenes we have.

```
www.somesite.com/index.abc
www.somesite.com/foo.def
www.somesite.com/foo/bar.abc
www.somesite.com/bar/foo/barfoo.def
...
```

with Apache .htaccess I can solve this problem by first testing for the existence of the page with a desired filetype.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.abc -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.abc [L]
```

I would also make sure that directory browsing is off and that trailing slashes would be removed

```
#ensure trailing slash is removed
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^(.*)(?:/)$ $1 [R=301,L]
```

all well and good for Apache, and for me relatively intuitive, but this is NGINX and quite frankly I have no idea how to solve this use-case.

All the similar use cases I have found deal with html & php ([How to remove both .php and .html extensions from url using NGINX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21911297/how-to-remove-both-php-and-html-extensions-from-url-using-nginx)) and simply use try_files until they fall-through to a named location that rewrites the uri with .php extension. This would work if one is only dealing with a single dynamic language and fails miserably if we have two dynamic languages.

So the question is how do I do something similar in NGINX like can be done with the .htaccess condition/rewrite above

any help would be appreciated!

Cheers
Gary

**UPDATE:**

I have been able to get it "mostly" working by using the standard php approach. The issue is *www.somesite.com* is being directed to *www.somesite.com/.php* instead of serving the default document. Trailing slashes are also being removed correctly.

so to recap:

```
www.somesite.com - not working - www.somesite.com/.php
www.somesite.com/foo - working
www.somesite.com/foo/bar - working
www.somesite.com/bar/foo/barfoo - working
```

here my config:

```
location / {
        index  index.php index.html
        autoindex off;

        #remove trailing slash
        rewrite ^/(.*)(?:/)$ /$1 permanent;

        #try html files or route to named location
        try_files $uri $uri.html @php;
    }

 location ~ \.php$ {
        ...
    }

 location @php {
        rewrite ^(.*)$ $1.php last;
    }
```

in other posts the try_files block looks like this: **try_files $uri $uri.html $uri/ @php;** the problem is if I add **$uri/** it will work for the default document e.g. serve **www.somesite.com** but all other urls like **www.somesite.com/foo/** or **www.somesite.com/foo/bar/** , which are also directories and have files of the same name, will be redirected to infinity instead of their respective pages.

Comment: What does `.abc` and `.def` mean? Are you removing `.html` and `.php` or something different? You can use `try_files` to link more than one named location and finish at the proxy.

Comment: .abc and .def are just file endings.. I didn't want to confuse the issue by specifying known file endings - just just as well could be, php, jsp, asp, cfm or any other dynamic language

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have three ways to process an extensionless URI, you would need three `location` blocks. You can use `try_files` to test for the existence of a file by type, and cascade to the next `location` block in the chain, if the file is not found. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) for details.

For example:

```
root /path/to/document/root;

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri.html $uri/ @php;
}
location @php {
    try_files $uri.php @proxy;
    fastcgi_pass ...;
    ...
}
location @proxy {
    proxy_pass ...;
}
```

The first block processes normal files within the document root. You probably have a `location ~ \.php$` block to process PHP files, and the second block is essentially a replica. The third block sends everything else upstream.

Comment: wow that seems overly complicated .. I missed that bit in the document (I think my eyes glazed over at that point) thanks for clarifying it in a bite sized chunk. I will give it a try.