# How to remove .php extension from url in nginx?

Tags: nginx

I am trying to remove `.php` extension from my website URL and I tried everything in StackOverflow but none helped me. This is my `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default` file :

```
##
# You should look at the following URL's in order to grasp a solid understanding
# of Nginx configuration files in order to fully unleash the power of Nginx.
# https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/
# https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/
# https://wiki.debian.org/Nginx/DirectoryStructure
#
# In most cases, administrators will remove this file from sites-enabled/ and
# leave it as reference inside of sites-available where it will continue to be
# updated by the nginx packaging team.
#
# This file will automatically load configuration files provided by other
# applications, such as Drupal or Wordpress. These applications will be made
# available underneath a path with that package name, such as /drupal8.
#
# Please see /usr/share/doc/nginx-doc/examples/ for more detailed examples.
##

# Default server configuration
#
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    # SSL configuration
    #
    # listen 443 ssl default_server;
    # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
    #
    # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
    #
    # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
    #
    # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
    # Don't use them in a production server!
    #
    # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

    root /var/www/public;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    server_name _;

    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    # pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server
    #
    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    #
    #   # With php-fpm (or other unix sockets):
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
    #   # With php-cgi (or other tcp sockets):
    #   fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    }

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}


# Virtual Host configuration for example.com
#
# You can move that to a different file under sites-available/ and symlink that
# to sites-enabled/ to enable it.
#
#server {
#   listen 80;
#   listen [::]:80;
#
#   server_name example.com;
#
#   root /var/www/example.com;
#   index index.html;
#
#   location / {
#       try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
#   }
#}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove both .php and .html extensions from url using NGINX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21911297/how-to-remove-both-php-and-html-extensions-from-url-using-nginx)

Comment: @0stone0 already tried it, but no, it's not working. I even can't start my web server using that code.

Comment: You shouldn't blindly copy/paste that solution, rather read it carefully and understand how to implement that answer in your custom config.

Comment: @0stone0 I know that the problem is that it's like I can't use `try_files $uri $uri.html $uri/ @extensionless-php;` and if I use this I get an error starting the web server.