# remove php extension nginx mamp pro 6

Tags: php, nginx, mamp, mamp-pro

I'm attempting to remove the `.php` extension from the URL of my website in the **NGINX** config. This is my first time using both **NGINX** *and* **MAMP Pro 6**, so forgive me if the answer seems obvious (I'm used to using `.htaccess`).

Using some answers from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21911297) thread, I've attempted:

- Editing the `conf` file directly (`/Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/conf/nginx.conf`).
- Editing the template `conf` file (File > Open Template > NGINX)
- Adding the entire `server` block to both of `Custom*` and `Additional parameters for the server directive` fields (attached image for reference).
- Adding just the contents of the `server` block to the same above fields.

This is a fresh project and I haven't modified the **NGINX** config at all before this.

```
server {
    index index.html index.php;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ $uri.html $uri.php$is_args$query_string;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
    }
}
```

[image: Reference Image]